# Custom function gets executed before OnInit in umbraco 4.9

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have the below code in the master page which allows user to select the country and it call the GetCountryCode() function written in the master page code behind

```
<umbraco:Macro ID="Lang" Alias="SelectCountry" runat="server" countryCode="<%$ WEB: GetCountryCode() %>" />
```

But when i am debugging the GetCountryCode() function is called first even before OnInit() function.
I need to do some initalisation on OnInit() function.

Does any one has any idea why the custom function is called before the OnInit() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought would be that the inline code is executed by umbraco when it renders the macros, which would happen prior to the code for the page is run.

If you could elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to look at a workaround?

Comment: After doing search on google a bit more, I found that the usercontrols are rendered before the OnInit() function of the master page is executed. Thats the reason why custom code is called first